# Rails Asset Pipeline Path Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails app running on a shared web host under a folder in my root direction called 'mintrus-ror/'. There is a symbolic link 'public_html/' that points to 'mintrus-ror/public/'. My Rails app loads in the browser but the stylesheets don't load. Looking at the rendered source I noticed the assets path it is using is '/mintrus-ror/assets/application.css'. I am trying to figure out how to change it so it does not include the 'mintrus-ror/' directory in the assets path. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a web server in front of your rails server? If so, is it possible that your web server is modifying the paths? Do the asset links look correct when you run your rails server locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with the `config.assets.manifest` configuration option in `config/environments/production.rb`. There are other variables that influence this, one being the web server configuration. I've got no recent (less than six years ago) experience with shared hosts, but I've read that on some systems, you can edit the `.htaccess` file.

I also presume that you're running in production mode and have previously compiled the assets with `rake assets:precompile` during your deployment step. Capistrano does this automatically when the asset pipeline integration is turned on.

The [Rails Guide on the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) may be useful.

Your best bet may be to host on Heroku. It's free for small sites and a lot less hassle.